# R dplyr perform interpolation for each group with varying min and max

Tags: r, dplyr, interpolation

Each segment has different `range`, for example A is from 1 to 3 while C is from 1 to 7.
For each segment, there can be missing time for which I want to perform interpolation (linear, spline, etc)

How can I do it within dplyr?

```
have <- data.frame(time   =c(1,3,1,2,5,1,3,5,7),
                 segment=c('A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'),
                 toInterpolate= c(0.12,0.31,0.15,0.24,0.55,0.11,0.35,0.53,0.79))
have


want <- data.frame(time   =c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                   segment=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C'),
                   Interpolated= c(0.12,0.21,0.31,0.15,0.24,0.34,0.41,0.55,0.11,0.28,0.35,0.45,0.53,0.69,0.79))
# note that the interpolated values here are just randomnly put, (not based on actual linear/spline interpolation)

want
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` to complete the sequence and `na.spline` from `zoo` for interpolation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

have %>%
  group_by(segment) %>%
  complete(time = min(time):max(time)) %>%
  mutate(toInterpolate = na.spline(toInterpolate))

#  segment  time toInterpolate
#   <chr>   <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1 A           1         0.12 
# 2 A           2         0.215
# 3 A           3         0.31 
# 4 B           1         0.15 
# 5 B           2         0.24 
# 6 B           3         0.337
# 7 B           4         0.44 
# 8 B           5         0.55 
# 9 C           1         0.11 
#10 C           2         0.246
#11 C           3         0.35 
#12 C           4         0.439
#13 C           5         0.53 
#14 C           6         0.641
#15 C           7         0.79
```

To create sequence for smaller granularities.

```
have %>%
  group_by(segment) %>%
  complete(time = min(time):max(time)) %>%
  mutate(toInterpolate = na.spline(toInterpolate)) %>%
  complete(time = seq(min(time), max(time), 0.1))
```

Comment: Thanks! @Ronak Shah, is there any way to control the granularity? For example, if I want to increase the granularity to 1 decimal point such as between 1 to 2, we would have 1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,...1.9.2.0, etc

Comment: Yes, you can use `seq` for that. `seq(1, 2, 0.1)` Or even something like this within each group `seq(min(toInterpolate), max(toInterpolate), length.out = n())`

Comment: Could you please update the above with `seq` example? I tried using the `full_seq` but not sure how to properly include it within the dplyr verb.

Comment: How you want `seq` to behave? What is your expected output? For the first group you have 0.12 for time = 1 and 0.31 for time = 3. What would be the value of time = 2?

Comment: I would leave the values to be interpolated by the functions, but I understand that the values to be interpolated would be too much and I guess some interpolation methods do not support such gaps?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include `seq` option.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself well enough. Let's take segment `A`, where we have its time vector to be `1` and `3`. With `complete` we can generate the sequence so that it becomes `1,2,3` and we can interpolate the missing values for `2` using `na.interpolate`. Now let's say we want to generate a different sequence such that for the time vector `1` and `3`, the complete sequence will be `1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,...2.8,2.9,3.0`. Previously we're interpolating only 1 value which is for time equals '2', but now we will interpolate for time at `1.1` up to `2.9`.

Comment: Basically how can I control the granularity of `complete()` because it only gives an increment of `1`. I would probably want a control on that such as having an increment by `0.1` or` 0.5`, etc. I think with `seq` or `full_seq` is possible but I'm not sure how properly integrate it within a `dplyr` pipeline and `group by`

Comment: Yes, you can control that with `seq`. Maybe the updated answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again @Ronak Shah